# Stop a '+' and other symbols from generating a formula with Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

These cell texts `= thinking`, `+ thinking`, `=+ thinking` show an error.
I found these workarounds:

1. enter an apostrophe `'` as the first character, right before the `+`.
2. enter the contents as a string formula like `="+5 blah"`.

But, I need to do this using Google Sheets API. I need to keep all the content of the cell unchanged.
Is it possible?

Comment: One try is to format the spreadsheet cells as ***Text*** before doing the import.

Comment: It was the first thing I thought about. But I can't find a command for this.

Comment: .............................See below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueInputOption='RAW'` fixed the problem.

The first one inserts text unchanged, the second one inserts formulas:

```
api.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=ssId, range='A1', body={'values': text},
    valueInputOption='RAW').execute()

api.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=ssId, range='B1', body={'values': [[formula]]},
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED').execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Format > Number > Plain Text**

[image]

Comment: My question is how to do it with Google Sheets API.

Comment: Lets leave this Question open.

Comment: Lets remove spammy answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data from the script itself, e.g, an import from a csv, you can append a single quote at the beginning to display it as is.

```
function forceString() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var txt = `="THINKING"`;
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(`'`+txt);
}
```

Comment: What if the data also has `"` or `'`? That's why I need to keep the cell text unchanged.

Comment: I edited my answer to use backticks as delimiters for the ````txt```` variable so you can use ````"```` or ````'````